# does sharing applied to child object

Tags: master-detail, owd

I have created custom object in MD relationship and set the master to private . when I Tried to applied sharing rule on Master . It is not effective on child object.

does sharing applied to child object in OWD Settings ?

Comment: Access for all child and grandchild records in Master-Detail relationship is driven by parent record's access.

Answer (score 2):

On the relationship field itself you can specify if read or edit access on parent is required to edit child.  Sharing will apply, but subject to the definition in the relationship field.

So if relationship field says edit on parent is needed to edit child, and your sharing rule only grants read access, then the user will not be able to edit child.

[See this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_security.htm&type=0&language=en_US) on custom object security for more details.  Re edit access, it says:

> “Edit” permission and either read or read/write access to the related master record, depending on the value of the Sharing Settingattribute of the master-detail relationship field on the detail object.

If it's a junction object there is a primary relationship and a secondary relationship, and there is some implication there that I need to look up as I don't recall the specifics.

Update - the primary and secondary relationship does not impact record access.  It is the combination of sharing settings on both m/d fields that controls access to junction object records. [See this post](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=0&language=en_US) for details.

Answer (score 0):

From [Salesforce docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US&type=0),

> When a custom object is on the detail side of a master-detail relationship with a standard object, its organization-wide default is set to Controlled by Parent and it is not editable.

<del>If you've got a Master-Detail between two custom objects, I think they have their own sharing settings.</del>

EDIT:
For custom object Master records, the sharing should apply to the Detail record. Do you have access to "View All Data" like an admin access?